# 'Undefined variable: clients (View: C:\wamp\www\myLSF\resources\views\back\clients\index.blade.php)'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a index.blade.php in view/back/client to list the clients.but I'm having this error.

> Undefined variable: clients (View:
> C:\wamp\www\myLSF\resources\views\back\clients\index.blade.php)

here is my index.blade.php

```
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name </th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Postal Code</th>
              <th>City</th>
               <th>Province</th>
               <th>Phone</th>
          

            </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
          @foreach($clients as $client)

          
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $client->id }} </td>
              <td>{{ $client->firstname }}</td>
              <td>{{ $client->lastname }}</td>
              <td>{{ $client->address }}</td>
              <td>{{ $client->postalcode }}</td>
              <td>{{ $client->city }}</td>
              <td>{{ $client->province }}</td>
              <td>{{ $client->phoneno }}</td>

            </tr>
            
           @endforeach
            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name </th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Postal Code</th>
              <th>City</th>
               <th>Province</th>
               <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
```

here is my clientcontroller.php

```
class clientController extends Controller
{

public function list()
{
   
    $clients = client::get();
   
    return view('/back/clients/index', compact('clients'));
 }
}
```

here is my client.php model

```
class client extends Model
 {
  use Notifiable;
  @var

 protected $table='clients';
  protected $fillable= 
    ['firstname','lastname','address','postalcode',
   'city','province','phoneno'];

    }
```

here i set the route for this in web.php

```
   Route::name('clients')->get('clients', 'clientController@list');
```

Comment: Where do you define `$clients` in the scope of your page? The error is saying the variable doesn't exist. Where do you call `clientController::list`? I don't really see how the `client` class is relevant to your question.

Comment: perhaps you have another controller method returning that view as well? because you are passing the data for the view instance in that controller method you are showing

Answer (score -1):

You need to import your `client` model into the `clientController.php` file.

To do this, add `use App\client` at the top, like so:

```
use App\client;

class clientController extends Controller
{
    public function list()
    {
        $clients = client::get();

        return view('/back/clients/index', compact('clients'));
    }
}
```

Comment: their `client` model is named `client` ... if the class reference wasn't right (wrong name or not aliased correctly) they would probably be getting a class not found error